How can I access "errorbar" objects with the interactive graph tool from matplotlib?
I have some sets of data that I have to plot ideally with error bars, thus I proceeded using the errorbar function from pyplot.
Now, sometimes from my datasets there are certain curves that I might want to take off the graph, but I can know which to remove only after plotting them, and they are different between data sets. I usually do that from the "Curves" sheet in the "figure options" from the interactive plot visualizer, but curves drawn with the errorbar function do not appear in this sheet. Why is that and how could I make them accessible?
A few pics to make it clearer:

Here I would like to hide from graph the dots 4 and 5. To do that I would go on the circled button:

And the "curves" sheet would appear. From there, I just select "linestile None" to hide the curves I want to hide.
In the case of the image I shown, I did plot everything using the normal plot function (error bars included), but if I try to plot the same thing using the errorbar function the "curves" sheet does not even appear, unless I plot something in the same figure using the normal plot function in which case the only curves I can modify are the latter.
Is there any way to make the errorbar curves behave like the normal ones?
